# Shell script to find the missing numbers in a file

Tags: bash, shell

Below is the example file I have with name `Weeks`:

```
2002
2004
2005
2006
2010
```

And I wanted a simple script to display the missing number from the files. I tried the below script but didn't get expected results.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='Weeks'
Sw=2001
while read line; do
  #Reading each line.
  if [ $line != $Sw ]
  then
    Sw=$(($Sw+1))
    echo "$line"
  else
    Sw=$(($Sw+1))
  fi
done < $filename
```

Expected output is:

```
2001
2003
2007
2008
2009
```

Please help me I don't why the above script is not giving me correct output.

Comment: Why is 2001 expected, but not 2011 or 9999?

Answer (score 3):

```sh
comm -13 Weeks <(seq 2001 2010)
```

That should do the trick.

`seq`:

```
NAME
       seq - print a sequence of numbers

SYNOPSIS
       seq [OPTION]... LAST
       seq [OPTION]... FIRST LAST
       seq [OPTION]... FIRST INCREMENT LAST

DESCRIPTION
       Print numbers from FIRST to LAST, in steps of INCREMENT.
       [...]
```

`comm`:

```
NAME
       comm - compare two sorted files line by line

SYNOPSIS
       comm [OPTION]... FILE1 FILE2

DESCRIPTION
       Compare sorted files FILE1 and FILE2 line by line.

       When FILE1 or FILE2 (not both) is -, read standard input.

       With no options, produce three-column output.  Column one contains lines unique to FILE1, column two contains lines unique to FILE2, and column three contains lines common to both files.

       -1     suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1)

       -2     suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2)

       -3     suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)
       [...]
```

The `<(...)` syntax tricks `comm` into believing, that the output of `seq` is actually a file.

In your original script there is an initial logic error, that follows execution until the end. Ask yourself, what happens in the very first iteration of the `while` loop: `$Sw` is `2001`, `$line` is `2002`. `$Sw` will be incremented to `2002`, but in the next iteration compared to `2004` and so on.

Additionally you print `$line`, which is the wrong variable.

A possible (albeit a bit inefficient) solution for the logic would be to nest another `for` loop in the while loop to look for and print items missing between the last `$line` value (that you need to store at the end of each loop in another variable) and the current `$line` value.

Comment: Hi Boldewyn, I tried this comm -13 weeks <(seq 2001 2010) for the weeks file as 
2002
2004
2005
2006
2010

and below is the O/P I got 
2001
2003
2004
2005
2006
2007
2008
2009

which is partially correct I didn't want 2004 2005 and 2006 also to be displayed.

And thanks for the correction on the script I will work on it.

Comment: Hm, strange. If I do this on my machine, I get the exact result: https://i.imgur.com/kufxInT.png Are you sure, that the `Weeks` file is “clean”? That is, no whitespace at line ends or other hidden characters in it?